# Account management tools supporting self-service registration and email verification?

Tags: ldap, directory, user-accounts, identity-management, lifecycle

I work in a university environment that has in the past offered services almost exclusively to university affiliates who already have "formal" accounts in central user database.  We are increasingly offering services to outside collaborators (hosted Subversion/git repositories, Wiki access, etc) that don't fit into this traditional model.

I am looking for a tool that would allow us to manage "lightweight" accounts, whereby "lightweight" I mean that:

- Users would be able to self-register accounts via a web interface.
- Accounts would be verified automatically via some sort of email + verification URL mechanism.

Having an account wouldn't grant access to anything by default (authorization would come through group membership or specific service ACLs).  This is a pretty typical model for popular web services, but I'm not having much luck finding a tool that implements this out of the box (and we don't really have the time or resources to write one ourselves).

There are a number of tools out there that provide self-service password change and metadata editing, but I haven't yet found one that handles the registration piece.  I was hoping that FreeIPA would handle this, but as far as I can tell it does not.

Are you aware of any tools that would enable this model?  I'm open to commercial solutions, if you've had a good experience with something like that.

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that you may need to pay someone to build it for you. It shouldn't take more than a few days of labour I imagine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [PWM](http://code.google.com/p/pwm/) it is a password self service but also supports self registration.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer!  It's not perfect but it appears to be the only solution in this space.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I don't know of any tools readily available to do this, but I have in the past written functionality like this for asp site that already had a db server setup and email program had been written to send emails from the db. It was relatively easy to do this.

Ashley is probably not far off the mark in suggesting having it custom wrote, but I would add if your in a university environment, abuse the students like my school does if you have a computer science department.